# Treeset Implementation of Map.Entry with Generic Types

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I'm building a frequency table implementation in which hashmap table elements are chained treesets. The key/value pair class is provided with a class definition as follows:

```
public class CountablePair<F, S extends Comparable<? super S>> implements Comparable<S> {
```

I wish to make a new class EntryTreeSet that implements Map.Entry, and includes within it a treeset of CountablePairs. My current code for the class declaration, its treeset variable, and its constructor are as follows:

```
public class EntryTreeSet<F,S> implements Map.Entry<F,S> {

private TreeSet<CountablePair<F,S>> tree;

public EntryTreeSet() {
    this.tree = new TreeSet<CountablePair<F,S>>();
}
```

However, this yields the following error statements:

> EntryTreeSet.java:19: error: type argument S#1 is not within bounds of type-variable S#2
>       private TreeSet> tree;
>                                       ^
>     where S#1,S#2 are type-variables:
>       S#1 extends Object declared in class EntryTreeSet
>       S#2 extends Comparable declared in class CountablePair
>   EntryTreeSet.java:22: error: type argument S#1 is not within bounds of type-variable S#2
>           this.tree = new TreeSet>();
>                                                   ^
>     where S#1,S#2 are type-variables:
>       S#1 extends Object declared in class EntryTreeSet
>       S#2 extends Comparable declared in class CountablePair

I was wondering how I would go about properly making my treeset hold instances of the CountablePair class.

Comment: One thing that stands out immediately: you are using a raw type: `TreeSet<CountablePair>` treats `CountablePair` as a raw type. You should specify its parameters in the declaration.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I've updated my question with the parameters specified.

Comment: Nitpick, but it should be a `TreeSetEntry`; the name `EntryTreeSet` leads one to believe that it's a TreeSet of Entries.

Comment: Also, are you sure that each entry of your TreeSet will have its own separate TreeSet?

Comment: I would try `class EntryTreeSet<F,S extends Comparable<? super S>> implements Map.Entry<F,S>` as the declaration of the second class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the only problem in your code is the absense of bounds for the `S` parameter in `EntryTreeSet` declaration. Such class declaration compiles correctly:

```
public class EntryTreeSet<F, S extends Comparable<? super S>> 
                         implements Map.Entry<F, S> {
```

Answer (score 0):

S is a raw type and that why the compilation error is coming.
Try the below code.

```
public class EntryTreeSet<F,S extends Comparable<? super S>> implements Map.Entry<F,S>
```